# pass list of int's as xml to be used with where clause

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am sending the following xml to a sql server stored procedure to be used in a where clause.

```
<root>
 <id>1</id>
 <id>2</id>
 <id>3</id>
</root
```

I am trying to work out a way to have a select statement where the where clause will check for any of the id values in the passed xml parameter.

Something like this:

```
@xml xml
select * from table
where (if exists (select id in @xml))
```

sorry i am not very good at sql.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Jamesla . . . Is the xml of type `xml` or of type `nvarchar`?

Comment: currently xml type but could be changed if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @xml xml;
set @xml = CAST('<root><id>1</id><id>2</id><id>3</id></root>' AS XML)

select id from mytable
where exists(select 1 from @xml.nodes('/root/id')as result(node)
             where node.value('(.)[1]', 'int') = id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I always refer to [this link](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#XML) from Erland Sommarskog for handling arrays in sql. It provides a good example and contrasts it with other mechanisms of passing in arrays to stored procedures.

Note if you are using SQL Server 2008 the he has [another link](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) detailing the use of table valued parameters. It might be overkill for your example, but if you are keen to learn what is available at your disposal, then its all worth a read.